# loop terminating early in C

Tags: c, loops, scanf, newline, do-while

Encountered a situation in my problem where I had to input multiple strings as input.
Now, my logic was to create a 2d array where (example)

```
Input:
ABD
okay
```

would be stored as

```
[['A','b','D'],['o','k','a','y']]
```

ideally, it should terminate when I input an empty string.

but my code(below) only takes first input and terminates.

```
    char str[100];
    char stringArray[50][100];
    int k,m,count=0,i=0,j=0;
    do {
        scanf("%[^\n]",&str);
        k=strlen(str);
        for(m=0;m<k;m++){
            stringArray[count][m]=str[m];
        }
        count++;
    }
    while (str[0] != '\0');
```

Comment: Please add a space so tnat `scanf("%[^\n]",&str);` becomes `scanf(" %[^\n]",str);` to remove the newline left in the buffer (and remove the `&` too).

Comment: Remove `&` in front of `str` too. But I would use `fgets` instead

Comment: `scanf()` can't read an empty string.

Comment: If you want to read a line, use `fgets()`.

Comment: `stringArray[count][m]=str[m];` this way you are not storing `\0` at the end of string, which will cause strange results

Comment: Note you are copying your strings without the null terminator. You also may overflow `str` in `scanf`. Consider using `strcpy` and `fgets`.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes the program works perfect now

Comment: @Barmar i changed termination condition from empty string to something else. thanks

Comment: @csavvy well that's intentional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the second argument of the call of scanf

```
scanf("%[^\n]",&str);
```

has the incorrect type `char ( * )[100]` instead of `char *`.

You need to write

```
scanf("%[^\n]",str);
```

However the new line character `'\n'` stays in the input buffer after this call.

At least you need to read it for example like

```
scanf( "%*c" );
```

Though it will be simpler to use the function `fgets` instead of scanf.

For example

```
fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );
```

And instead of the do-while loop it will be better to use a while loop.

For example

```
while ( fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin ) != NULL && str[0] != '\n' )
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: instead of `str[0] != '\0'`, it would be `str[0] != '\n'`.

Comment: @mr.loop The new line character can be absent in the string.

Comment: your code will not stop taking input after encountering an empty string, because empty string will be having the newline character